# After building a simple GUI in tkinter that prompts users to enter a value, how do you actually use their entered values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, user-interface, tkinter

I appreciate your patience. I'm new to Python and Tkinter.

I have the following code that prompts users to upload a file and a win rate percentage. I have written a script in a different file that uses pandas to perform a series of operations on the file(s). The problem is I'm struggling to actually use the values the user enters and am currently not sure how I would actually run the script I've written on the users values. I'm certain it's a really simple fix but for the life of me I'm struggling to figure it out. I would to actually run the script once the users have inputted their values and they click "start conversion" button. Any help you can provide would be most appreciated, thanks :)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

window = Tk()

window.title("Pipeline tool")
window.geometry("250x170")



lbl = Label(window, text="UPLOAD", font=("Arial Bold", 15))
lbl3 = Label(window, text = "Please upload your files into the fields below, than hit convert.", font = ("Arial Bold ", 10))

plbl = Label(window, text="Revenue File", font=("Arial ", 10))
hclbl = Label(window, text="Win Rate Percentage", font=("Arial ", 10))



lbl.grid(column=10, row=0)
lbl3.grid(column=10, row = 10)
plbl.grid(column = 8, row = 20)
hclbl.grid(column = 8, row = 30)
window.geometry('500x500')


txt = Entry(window,width=100)
txt.grid(column=10, row=20)

txt = Entry(window,width=100)
txt.grid(column=10, row=30)
#files = filedialog.askopenfilenames()

def clicked():

    files = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
    messagebox.showinfo('Successful Upload!', 'Your file has been successfully uploaded!')


def clicked1():


    messagebox.showinfo('Please wait', 'Your files are being read. The output should download shortly. !')

btn = Button(window, text="Start Conversion", command= clicked1)
btn.grid(column=10, row=40)

btn = Button(window, text="UPLOAD", command= clicked)
btn.grid(column=13, row=20)

btn = Button(window, text="ENTER", command= clicked)
btn.grid(column=13, row=30)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: So from what I can understand , you basically want to get/retrieve the entry values and use it somewhere else.Am i right ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I can see now I made the question far too wordy

Answer (score 1):

To store the file paths, create a global variable (I've called it `userFiles`) to store the files when the user clicks upload. To get the value in the win rate entry box, use `entry.get()`. I've also added some validation to your code so the user has to upload a file and give a win rate before doing calculations.
Here's the code:

```
window.title("Pipeline tool")
window.geometry("250x170")

userFiles = None

lbl = Label(window, text="UPLOAD", font=("Arial Bold", 15))
lbl3 = Label(window, text = "Please upload your files into the fields below, than hit convert.", font = ("Arial Bold ", 10))

plbl = Label(window, text="Revenue File", font=("Arial ", 10))
hclbl = Label(window, text="Win Rate Percentage", font=("Arial ", 10))

lbl.grid(column=10, row=0)
lbl3.grid(column=10, row = 10)
plbl.grid(column = 8, row = 20)
hclbl.grid(column = 8, row = 30)
window.geometry('500x500')


fileEntry = Entry(window,width=100)
fileEntry.grid(column=10, row=20)

winEntry = Entry(window,width=100)
winEntry.grid(column=10, row=30)
#files = filedialog.askopenfilenames()

def clicked():
    files = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
    if files:
        global userFiles
        userFiles = files
        messagebox.showinfo('Successful Upload!', 'Your file has been successfully uploaded!')


def clicked1():
    global userFiles
    winRate = winEntry.get()
    if winRate != "" and userFiles != "" and userFiles != None:
        print(winRate, userFiles)
        #Do your calulations here...
        messagebox.showinfo('Please wait', 'Your files are being read. The output should download shortly. !')
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Error","Please fill all fields in")

btn = Button(window, text="Start Conversion", command= clicked1)
btn.grid(column=10, row=40)

btn = Button(window, text="UPLOAD", command= clicked)
btn.grid(column=13, row=20)

btn = Button(window, text="ENTER", command= clicked)
btn.grid(column=13, row=30)
```